# Red Hat/CentOS cluster compared to HeartBeat?

Tags: centos, redhat, cluster, heartbeat

What are the main differences (other then UI) between RH/CentOS cluster and heartbeat?

I have some experience using heartbeat, but wondered what the RH/CentOS provides, and looking at docs it seems more or less the same, plus shared storage support (which can be done on heartbeat via GFS).

Comment: http://people.redhat.com/ccaulfie/docs/Whither%20cman.pdf  This may help, in RHEL6+ they are moving to standard modules (corosync) instead of their custom-built one.  I would think there would be very little difference between them at that point. (Since Heartbeat is deprecated by Pacemaker, which uses corosync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if using centos5 and setting up Redhat Cluster with GFS.... just, don't. either use what @devicenull suggested (centos6, etc.) or stick with heartbeat/pacemaker specifically. RH cluster on centos5 is fundamentally broken due to some locking issues with the kernel that nobody really seems to have figured out.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, saved us quite some time indeed :).

Comment: Is it stable in centos 6?